# TSQL: recursive date split by quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have a simple query

```sql
select
from_date, to_date
from datatable
order by from_date
```

which results in

```
from_date   to_date
2018-01-01  2018-04-30
2018-05-01  2018-12-31
```

I want to split the date ranges into quarters. So far I'm resulting with this:

```sql
WITH temp AS 
(
   SELECT 
   cast(sd.from_date as date) from_date, 
   cast(dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(quarter, 1, cast(sd.from_date as date))) as date)  AS end_date,
   cast(sd.to_date as date) as actual_enddate
   FROM (select cast(from_date as date) from_date, to_date from datatable) sd
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  
   dateadd(day,1,cast(t.end_date as date)) end_date, 
   CASE 
      WHEN dateadd(quarter, 1,t.end_date) < t.actual_enddate THEN dateadd(quarter, 1,t.end_date) 
      ELSE t.actual_enddate 
     END AS end_date,
   cast(t.actual_enddate as date) actual_enddate
   FROM temp t
  WHERE t.end_date != t.actual_enddate
)
SELECT 
t.from_date, 
t.end_date
FROM temp t
ORDER BY t.from_date
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

and my current output is:

```
from_date   end_date
2018-01-01  2018-03-31
2018-04-01  2018-04-30
2018-05-01  2018-07-31
2018-08-01  2018-10-31
2018-11-01  2018-12-31
```

---

I would like to split those records to full quarters to receive as follows:

```
from_date   end_date
2018-01-01  2018-03-31
2018-04-01  2018-04-30
2018-05-01  2018-06-31
2018-07-01  2018-09-31
2018-10-01  2018-12-31
```

Comment: Sample data would really help here and an explanation. I have no idea how you get from your initial dataset to your end result.

Comment: I've edited the post by pasting an output of my current solution

Comment: I still don't understand. Why does January retain 100, but April's value is reduced by 2 thirds? You need to explain. *"a respective value I would like to have calculated"* Calculated from what? If we don't know what that calculation is, we can't help you.

Comment: As a quick shot I'd suggest to introduce a Tally or a numbers table and *join* your data on an *is within intervall* condition. The computations might be solved with windowing functions (e.g. `COUNT() OVER()`), but this is not really clear. Please try to set up a *stand alone minimal example* to reproduce your issue (please read [mcve]).

Comment: @Larnu first step is to receive correct [from_date] and [end date] 

(currently  [end_date] in 3rd line, [from_date] and [end_date] in 4th line and [from_date] in 5th line are wrong: 1 month too much)

Comment: @Shnugo I've edited a task once again to focus on ONLY on data ranges to be correct

Comment: @golazo problems like these become trivial once you use [a Calendar table](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date arithmetic for this problem is quite confusing.  You seem to be counting months and that I find that difficult when you use the quarter end date.

So the following adds one date to bring the values to the next month.  This is just for the calculation, but it simplifies the partitioning logic.

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT id, sd.from_date as within_quarter_start_date,
             (CASE WHEN quarter_end < to_date THEN quarter_end ELSE to_date END) as within_quarter_end_date,
             DATEADD(quarter, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, from_date), 0) as quarter_start,
             v.quarter_end,
             DATEADD(day, 1, sd.to_date) as to_date, 
             sd.value, 1 as lev
      FROM datatable sd CROSS APPLY
           (VALUES (DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, from_date) + 1, 0))) v(quarter_end)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(quarter, 1, quarter_start)),
             (CASE WHEN DATEADD(quarter, 1, quarter_end) < to_date THEN DATEADD(quarter, 1, quarter_end) ELSE to_date END) as within_quarter_end_date,
             DATEADD(quarter, 1, quarter_start),
             DATEADD(quarter, 1, quarter_end),
             to_date,
             value, lev + 1
      FROM cte
      WHERE quarter_end < to_date and lev < 10
     )
select within_quarter_start_date as from_date,
       dateadd(day, -1, within_quarter_end_date) as to_date,
       value * (datediff(month, within_quarter_start_date, within_quarter_end_date) ) / 3.0,
       quarter_start, quarter_end
from cte
order by 1, 2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd7c4c12dbd71dba942e015e4efe0f96) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Does this resemble what you're looking for?

```html
DECLARE @datatable TABLE
(
 from_date DATE,
 to_date DATE,
 value FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @datatable
(from_date, to_date, value)
VALUES   
('2018-01-01','2018-04-30','100'),
('2018-05-01','2018-12-31','100')

;WITH temp AS 
(
SELECT 
 sd.from_date,
 DATEADD(DAY,-1, DATEADD(MONTH, 3 - ((MONTH(sd.from_date) -1) % 3), sd.from_date)) AS end_date,
 sd.to_date As actual_enddate, 
 sd.value
FROM @datatable sd
UNION ALL
SELECT  
 DATEADD(DAY,1, t.end_date) end_date, 
 CASE 
  WHEN DATEADD(QUARTER, 1,t.end_date) < t.actual_enddate THEN EOMONTH(DATEADD(QUARTER, 1, t.end_date) )
  ELSE t.actual_enddate 
 END AS end_date,
 t.actual_enddate As actual_enddate,
 value
FROM temp t
WHERE t.end_date != t.actual_enddate
)
SELECT 
t.from_date, 
t.end_date, 
ROUND((100.0/3.0) * (DATEDIFF(MONTH, t.from_date, DATEADD(DAY, 1, t.end_date))), 2) As Value
FROM temp t
ORDER BY t.from_date
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Not really. First, I want to divide those two source rows into correct quarters from and to date. Then - I would like to calculate a part of quarter multiplied by value.